# running a while loop in python and functions not defined

Tags: python-3.x, function, while-loop

Hi I have this code below and I want the while loop to keep on getting an input from the user whenever the user enters an empty value or doesn't input any value, the program should keep on prompting the user to enter at least a single character, but the code seems to run even though I don't enter any value, thus an empty string the code still executes the (function) in the code, and also I get error "Function not defined"

```
word = ""
while True:
    if word != "":
       def str_analysis(string):

           if string.isdigit():
              if int(string) > 99:
                 print (string,"Is a big number")
              else:
                  print(string,"Small number")
           elif string.isalpha():
                print(string,"Is all alphabetical characters")
           else:
              print(string,"is multiple character types")


    word = input ("Enter a word or integer:")
    break
str_analysis(word)
```

Comment: define str_analysis(string) function outside if structure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you expect to happen. word is equal to "" so the if block won't run, so the function won't get defined. Next, we ask the user for input and after that break the loop. Then you try and call a function that was never defined.

What you wanna do is put a break at the end of the function and get rid of the existing one.